# How to test an Azure Function that uses Context?

Tags: python, azure, unit-testing, azure-functions

I'm writing an Azure Function that uses context (for monitoring purposes), this is what my function looks like:

```
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(
        "{}\t{}".format(
            context.invocation_id, context.function_name
        )
    )
    reponse = "foo"    
    return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(reponse), mimetype="application/json")
```

And I want to write integration test for this function, like this:

```
import unittest
import azure.functions as func
from MyFunc import main    

class TestMyFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_myfunc(self):
        req = func.HttpRequest(
            method="GET",
            body=None,
            url="/api/myfunc",
        )
        ctx = ??
        reponse = main(req, ctx) # This part fails because of the context

        self.assertEqual(
            reponse.get_body(),
            b'foo',
        )
```

How can I create a [Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.context?view=azure-python) object to pass to my Azure Function?

Comment: May be you can create [something like](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-library/blob/800a75b91b4b15aef09e551b053c33c7184d6b99/tests/test_http_asgi.py#L106) this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [*`Context`* is an ABC(Abstract Base Class) class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC), so you cannot directly instantiate. Instead you could [subclass the *`func.Context`* class](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-library/blob/800a75b91b4b15aef09e551b053c33c7184d6b99/tests/test_http_asgi.py#L106) and use the instance of that class as `ctx`

```
class MockContext(func.Context):
    def __init__(self, ii, fn, fd):
        self._invocation_id = ii
        self._function_name = fn
        self._function_directory = fd

    @property
    def invocation_id(self):
        return self._invocation_id

    @property
    def function_name(self):
        return self._function_name

    @property
    def function_directory(self):
        return self._function_directory

ctx = MockContext("Some dummy values")
```